# Check if a specific UITableViewCell is visible in a UITableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` and some `UITableViewCells` which i have created manually via the *Interface Builder*. I've assigned each cell an `outlet`, and im connecting them to the `UITableView` in the `CellForRowAtIndexPath` method. In this method, I use the `switch(case)` method to make specific cells appear in the `UITableView`, depends on the case.

Now, I want to find a specific cell and check if he is exists within the `UITableView`. I use the method: `UITableView.visibleCells` to get an array of the cells in the table view. My question is - how can i check if a specific cells exists in the array? can I use the outlet that i've assigned to it somehow? -  (The best solution),OR, can I use an identifier and how?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Note that you can as well use `indexPathsForVisibleRows` this way:

```
    NSUInteger index = [_people indexOfObject:person];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:index inSection:0];
    if ([self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows containsObject:indexPath]) {
      [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] 
                            withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }
```

If you have the indexPath (and don't need the actual Cell) it might be *cheaper*.

PS: `_people` is the `NSArray` used as my backend in this case.

Comment: This solution is better than the accepted solution in most cases.

Answer (score 19):

```
if ([tableView.visibleCells containsObject:myCell])
{
    // Do your thing
}
```

This assumes that you have a separate instance variable containing the cell you are interested in, I think you do from the question but it isn't clear.

Comment: Thanks, it's another way of implementing the solution that Sorig gave me :)

Comment: This is the correct answer to the original question, if a cell is visible. Thanks for the clean and simple answer.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the UITableView method:

```
[tableView indexPathForCell:aCell];
```

If the cell doesn't exist in the tableView it will return nil. Otherwise you will get the cell's NSIndexPath.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in Swift to check if the `UITableViewCell` is visible:

```
let indexPathToVerify = IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)
let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPathToVerify)

if tableView.visibleCells.contains(cell) {
    // the cell is visible
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since iOS 7, `indexPathForVisibleRows` will contain a row that is under the translucent navigation bar hence you now need to do this:

```
[self.tableView indexPathsForRowsInRect:self.tableView.safeAreaLayoutGuide.layoutFrame]
```